# Como puedo hacer para que en select me salga la info de la base de datos con php a la hora de actualizar ese registro? tengo un problema extraño

Tags: php, base-de-datos, poo, mvc

tengo un problema que me parece muy extraño con un select y php.

Tanto en mi tabla de la base de datos como en una tabla donde muestro los datos registrados se me muestran los datos, pero luego de los 3 select que tengo para elegir una de las opciones siempre el de abajo no me aparece a la hora de editar. Sin embargo en la base de datos y en la tabla sí se muestra el dato correcto. Sólo cuando vuelvo a indicar la opcion en editar y guardo se queda seleccionada cuando vuelvo a entrar.

Me parece muy extraño este suceso porque tengo el mismo código en los 3 select y no entiendo porque en los 2 primeros funciona correctamente y en el ultimo no.

El código del controller es el siguiente:

```
 public static function editar_asignar_posgrado(Router $router) {
    iniciarSesion();
    isAdmin();

    $alumPosgrado = AlumPosgrado::find($_GET['id']);

    $posgrados = Posgrado::all();
    $alumnos = Alumno::all();

    $alertas = [];

    unset($alumPosgrado->alumno);
    unset($alumPosgrado->nombrePosgrado);

    //debuguear($alumPosgrado);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $alumPosgrado->sincronizar($_POST);
        $alertas = $alumPosgrado->validar();

        //debuguear($posgrado);

        if(empty($alertas)) {
            
            //debuguear($alumPosgrado);
            $alumPosgrado->guardar();
            header('Location: /alumnos');
        }
    }

    $router->render('alumnos/editarAsignar-posgrado', [
        'alumPosgrado' => $alumPosgrado,
        'posgrados' => $posgrados,
        'alumnos' => $alumnos,
        'alertas' => $alertas
    ]);
}
```

El código de la view es el siguiente:

```
                <label for="lenguaVehicular">Lengua Vehicular:</label>
                <select name="lenguaVehicular">
                    <option disabled selected value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaVehicular === 'Español') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Español">Español</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaVehicular === 'Inglés') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Inglés">Inglés</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaVehicular === 'Francés') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Francés">Francés</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaVehicular === 'Italiano') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Italiano">Italiano</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaVehicular === 'Alemán') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Alemán">Alemán</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="lenguaPartida">Lengua Partida:</label>
                <select name="lenguaPartida">
                    <option disabled selected value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaPartida === 'Español') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Español">Español</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaPartida === 'Inglés') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Inglés">Inglés</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaPartida === 'Francés') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Francés">Francés</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaPartida === 'Italiano') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Italiano">Italiano</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaPartida === 'Alemán') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Alemán">Alemán</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="campo">
                <label for="lenguaMeta">Lengua Meta:</label>
                <select name="lenguaMeta">
                    <option disabled selected value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta === 'Español') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Español">Español</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta === 'Inglés') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Inglés">Inglés</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta === 'Francés') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Francés">Francés</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta === 'Italiano') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Italiano">Italiano</option>
                    <option <?php if($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta === 'Alemán') { echo "selected";} ?> value="Alemán">Alemán</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No pongas el selected en los options por defecto: `<option disabled selected` a ver si con eso lo logras, aunque lo dudo porque mirando el inspector no aparece ningun selected en los idiomas de Lengua Meta, por lo tanto me inclino a que no recuperas bien ese valor de `$alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta`.  Hazle un `echo $alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta` a ver si sale algo o está vacio.

Comment: Donde te refieres que haga el echo $alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta ?

Comment: En cualquier parte de ese cacho de código, donde teoricamente ya esté resuelta esa propiedad de `$alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta`.  Es solo para depuración, para ver si sale algo, pues no has puesto como consigues el $alumPosgrado en la pregunta y a ciegas poco más puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo indico en la pregunta. $alumPosgrado lo traigo de un controller que lo mando despues a esa view. 

He añadido echo $alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta y me devuelve como valor 'Francés' que es lo que está en la base de datos.

Comment: Pues debería funcionarte bien, a menos que tengas algun problema de caracteres (lo digo por el acento, comprueba que no este guardado así en la base de datos:  `Franc&eacute;s`)

Comment: Ya lo comprobé, es más, hice una prueba quitando todos los acentos y seguía sin funcionar. Me parece extrañísimo por qué sucede esto cuando en los otros dos funciona perfectamente

Comment: Acabo de intentar reproducir tu error y no he podido. Para ello simplemente he puesto esto encima de los select para conseguir el objeto: `<?php
$alumPosgrado = new StdClass();
$alumPosgrado->lenguaVehicular = "Alemán";
$alumPosgrado->lenguaPartida = 'Alemán';
$alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta = 'Francés'
?>` y así sí me funciona. No se que más puedo hacer para ayudarte

Comment: El problema que le veo a eso, es que para el resto de registros que tengo en la tabla, a la hora de editarlos, me muestras esas opciones en los select (Aleman, Aleman, Frances).

Comment: Creo que he encontrado cual es el error. Me está generando la variable al crear el registro un espacio al final del string. ["lenguaMeta"]=>
  string(9) "Francés ".

Esto me lo han hecho ya algunas variables y aunque estoy utilizando la funcion trim(): echo trim($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta = 'Español'); a la hora de crear los registros, no me está eliminado el espacio al final. A qué se puede deber esto?

Comment: Deberias repasar la creación de usuarios (no la edición) para aplicar el trim() correctamente justo antes de guardarse en la base de datos. De todos modos, para usarlo tal como lo tienes ahora, puedes ponerlo así: `if(trim($alumPosgrado->lenguaMeta) === 'Francés')`

Comment: He hecho eso y parece que de momento se ha arreglado. Muchas gracias masterguru

Comment: Moraleja: siempre es mejor trabajar con identificadores numéricos, en este caso una columna `lenguaID` en la tabla de tipo `INTEGER`, poner ese dato en el `value` de los `option` y usarlo para las comparaciones. Eso no quita que limpies los datos de espacios en blanco al momento de guardarlos en la tabla y punto.